# Problema al mostrar todos los registros de mi base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, html, base-de-datos, select

Hola comunidad tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una pagina web en la cual muestro mis registros en una tabla son mas de **5,000** pero solo me deja mostras **2,000** o **2,500**.

Esta es la Query

```
SELECT
  V.idViaje, V.CartaPorte, V.Referencia,
  C.RazonSocial AS Cliente, V.Destino,
  V.Contenedor1, V.Contenedor2, V.Contenedor3, V.Contenedor4,
  V.Contenedor5, V.Contenedor6, V.Contenedor7, V.Contenedor8,
  V.Contenedor9, V.Contenedor10, V.FechaAlta, V.Pagado
FROM viajes V
LEFT JOIN clientes C 
  ON V.idCliente=C.idCliente
ORDER BY V.idViaje DESC
LIMIT 0,1000
```

Pero en mi local host si me muestra todos los registros, solo le quite el **LIMIT 0,1000**

```
SELECT
  V.idViaje, V.CartaPorte, V.Referencia,
  C.RazonSocial AS Cliente, V.Destino,
  V.Contenedor1, V.Contenedor2, V.Contenedor3, V.Contenedor4,
  V.Contenedor5, V.Contenedor6, V.Contenedor7, V.Contenedor8,
  V.Contenedor9, V.Contenedor10, V.FechaAlta, V.Pagado
FROM viajes V
LEFT JOIN clientes C 
  ON V.idCliente=C.idCliente
ORDER BY V.idViaje DESC
```

Se tiene que hacer alguna configuración adicional?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Clave</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>
      <th>Referencia</th>
      <th>Carta Porte</th>
      <th>Cliente</th>
      <th>Destino</th>
      <th>Contenedor</th>
      <?php
if($_COOKIE["lvl"]==1){
?>
      <th>Pagado</th>
      <?php
}
?>
      <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
if($_COOKIE["lvl"]==1){
    $result=query("SELECT V.idViaje,V.CartaPorte,V.Referencia,C.RazonSocial AS Cliente,V.Destino,V.Contenedor1,V.Contenedor2,V.Contenedor3,V.Contenedor4,V.Contenedor5,V.Contenedor6,V.Contenedor7,V.Contenedor8,V.Contenedor9,V.Contenedor10,V.FechaAlta,V.Pagado FROM viajes V LEFT JOIN clientes C ON V.idCliente=C.idCliente ORDER BY V.idViaje DESC LIMIT 0,1000");
}else{
    $result=query("SELECT V.idViaje,V.Referencia,V.CartaPorte,C.RazonSocial AS Cliente,V.Destino,V.Contenedor1,V.Contenedor2,V.Contenedor3,V.Contenedor4,V.Contenedor5,V.Contenedor6,V.Contenedor7,V.Contenedor8,V.Contenedor9,V.Contenedor10,V.FechaAlta FROM viajes V LEFT JOIN clientes C ON V.idCliente=C.idCliente WHERE V.idCliente=".$_COOKIE["idUsuario"]." ORDER BY V.idViaje DESC LIMIT 0,200");
    //$result=query("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE idCliente=".$_COOKIE["idUsuario"]);
}
$contenedores="";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$contenedores="";
for ($i=1; $i <=10 ; $i++) {
    $contenedor='Contenedor'.$i; 
    if($row[$contenedor] != ''){
        
        $contenedores.=(empty($contenedores))? $row[$contenedor]: ' - '.$row[$contenedor];
    }
}
?>
      <tr class="gradeA" style="text-align:center;">
        <td>
          <?php echo $row["idViaje"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td style="width:110px">
          <?php echo $row["FechaAlta"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row["CartaPorte"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row["Referencia"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row["Cliente"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row["Destino"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $contenedores; ?>
        </td>
```

Este es el Logs

1. [Wed Jul 24 09:20:39.682835 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 4772:tid 696] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
2. [Wed Jul 24 09:20:39.714051 2019] [core:warn] [pid 4772:tid 696] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
3. [Wed Jul 24 09:20:39.714051 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 4772:tid 696] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
4. [Wed Jul 24 09:20:39.745295 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4772:tid 696] AH00455: Apache/2.4.38 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1a PHP/7.3.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
5. [Wed Jul 24 09:20:39.745295 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4772:tid 696] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Jan 18 2019 12:31:19
6. [Wed Jul 24 09:20:39.745295 2019] [core:notice] [pid 4772:tid 696] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
7. [Wed Jul 24 09:20:39.760943 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4772:tid 696] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5852
8. [Wed Jul 24 09:20:40.385795 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 5852:tid 704] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
9. [Wed Jul 24 09:20:40.432632 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 5852:tid 704] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
10. [Wed Jul 24 09:20:40.448283 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5852:tid 704] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
11. [Wed Jul 24 09:52:18.841420 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 5852:tid 1976] [client ::1:53922] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\containerallrisk-com\inc\menu.php on line 8
12. [Wed Jul 24 09:52:18.841420 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 5852:tid 1976] [client ::1:53922] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: lvl in C:\xampp\htdocs\containerallrisk-com\inc\menu.php on line 16
13. [Wed Jul 24 09:52:18.841420 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 5852:tid 1976] [client ::1:53922] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: lvl in C:\xampp\htdocs\containerallrisk-com\inc\menu.php on line 43

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: saludos podrias especificar que lenguaje usas para esto como PHP u otro, ademas la manera en la que estas mostrando los datos en tu pagina html agrega tu código para darte una mejor respuesta..!!

Comment: fijate en los logs de apache que error retorna

Comment: Añade un paginador a tu consulta, asi no saturas la comunicacion, memoria y muestra de datos, ninguna persona lee 5000 registros a la vez en una pagina.

Comment: Modifique mi pregunta y agregue mi codigo que utilizo para mostrar los registros, donde se encuentran los logs? en XAMPP?

Comment: Si tengo un paginador el cual puede ver ya sea de 10, 20, 50 o 100 registros sino encuentra el registro puede pasar a la siguiente pagina

Comment: En tu path de instalacion del XAMPP ejemplo C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log considerando que usas windows

Comment: @oegpyg agregue los logs en mi pregunta, pero en el localhost si me funciona bien

Comment: Tal vez tengas un error con tu llave foranea ya que estas mostrando con el igual - igual y puede que haya datos sin la llave foranea y por ende no se reconoce estos valores. checa si tu tabla están realmente llenas.

Comment: el log que debes mirar es de tu servidor, en las ultimas lineas debe estar el mensaje de error.

Comment: Que servidor usas para tus pruebas? Te pregunto porque tal vez este limitado, ya que por experiencia donde hacia consultas que devolvían muchos registros (creo eran como 1200 o algo así) salían ese tipo de errores y en mi caso era porque el servidor estaba demasiado limitado... :/

Comment: Estoy usando phpmyadmin 4.8.5 (subí foto a mi pregunta) y pues tengo todo ilimitado

Comment: deberias primero verificar que recibas el valor de "lvl" dado que en tu log de errores te menciona que no esta definido "undefined"...

Comment: el valor $_COOKIE["lvl"] lo utilizo para dar privilegios por ejemplo administrador o usuario como podras ver dice $_COOKIE["lvl"]==1 que es el administrador y puede ver 1000 registros el cual quiero que vea todos (7,400). Si le quito LIMIT 0,1000 localmente si me muestra los 7,400 registros pero ya en el servidor no

Answer (score 0):

Primero prueba ese query directo en la base de datos (por phpmyadmin y otro gestor), si retorna la cantidad que esperas entonces hay un error en la lógica de tu código.

Segundo verifica que el código esté recibiendo los valores de $_COOKIE["lvl"] y $_COOKIE["idUsuario"].

Tercero, quita las condicionales y paginador y prueba que se obtengan los registros que esperas. Luego incluyes las condicionales y verifica dónde puede ocurrir un error.

Comment: Probe el query en mi phpmyadmin local y de servidor y si me retorno todos los registros, el valor $_COOKIE["lvl"] lo utilizo para dar privilegios por ejemplo administrador o usuario como podras ver dice $_COOKIE["lvl"]==1 que es el administrador y puede ver 1000 registros el cual quiero que vea todos (7,400)